# I'm using three questions in a list inside quotation marks, would I separate with a comma, semicolon, or nothing? Are the question marks even needed?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons, quotation-marks, question-mark

A sentence with a list of questions inside quotation marks, how do I separate them? I can't find a solid answer anywhere.

Option 1:
In simple terms, Naikan is based on three questions: “What have I received?” “What have I given?” and “What troubles and difficulties have I caused?”

Option 2:
In simple terms, Naikan is based on three questions: “What have I received?”; “What have I given?”; and “What troubles and difficulties have I caused?”.

Option 3:
In simple terms, Naikan is based on three questions: “What have I received?”, “What have I given?”, and “What troubles and difficulties have I caused?”.

Or would it be no question mark at all?
In simple terms, Naikan is based on three questions: “What have I received”, “What have I given”, and “What troubles and difficulties have I caused."

The quotation marks have to be in it.

Answer (score -3):

Not *all* the question marks are needed and famously, you wouldn’t start from there. Rather, you might ask “*If* I'm using three questions in a list inside quotation marks, would I separate *them* with a comma, semicolon, or nothing?”

Whichever applies, could you drop the initial phrase “In simple terms, Naikan is based on three questions: …”? It makes no difference.

The problem here is that instead of actually making a single list, you’ve tried to combine three individual items and keep them separate… which is almost as far from a list as you could get.

If they’re separate, treat them separately. If they really form a list, use one set of quotation marks.

“… What have I received? What have I given? What troubles and difficulties have I caused?”

Comment: Oh, and gosh, downvoters… what are you suggesting?

Comment: Reasly? Then why couod you not accept that this was marked as a duplicate by Laurel, Peter Shor , J. Taylor, Jason Bassford, Mark Beadles Nov 19 at 12:46?

This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.